# Проблема с русским в консоли после компиляции

Tags: c++, borland-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");
   cout << "Этот текст будет каракулями";
   return 0;
}
```

Немогу понять, как сделать, чтобы была поддержка OEM.

Comment: @Abyx, вроде не дубликат. Тут же тег [tag:borland-c++].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

char* convert(char* str)
{
   char* s;
   CharToOemA(str, s); // Функция и конвертация.
   return s;
}

int main()
{
   cout<<convert("Привет Мир!!!");
   cin.get();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Эм.. В функцию передаётся неинициализированный указатель, который потом возвращается. Судя по msdn, передаётся по значению. Как это вообще может работать? А если по ссылке и функция сама выделяет память, то кто-то её должен освобождать.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы в консоли выводился русский текст, надо использовать кодировку `Cp866`. Не знаю, как в C++ кодировку изменить но, думаю, идея поможет.

Comment: в учебниках сказана что это поле setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian") является изменением кодировки на OEM866

Answer (score 0):

Нормально отработало на Mac OS X и на Debian GNU/Linux... В винде помню ставил просто setlocale(0,""); и все работало хорошо.

Comment: unix это и не нужно, а вот в win не проходит, может в Embarcadero RAD SDtudio

Comment: а вариант сменить кодировку консоли? предложенные решения, на мой взгляд, это просто костыли привязанные к системе.

Answer (score -1):

Если ты пишешь в Visual Studio, то есть такой способ

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

       cout << "Этот текст будет нормальным, если после компиляции и запуска ты в        свойствах консоли поменяешь шрифт на Lucida Console";

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: спосибо за ответ , но я в RAD Studio

Comment: В RAD Studio нет библиотеки stdafx.h

Comment: stdafx.h это стандартная библиотека для VS.

Comment: > stdafx.h это стандартная библиотека для VS.

WTF!?!?!? это файл из проекта, а не часть стандартной библиотеки