# Какую кодировку хавает виндоус консоль?

Tags: cmd, perl

Есть программа на перле, запускаю в цмд, получаю почту. В какую кодировку ее перекодировать, чтобы я мог увидеть русский текст в консоли?

Answer (score 1):

Cp866, уже обсуждалось: [проблема с русским в консоли после компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/15744/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).